# Automate computer input for program

Tags: windows, automation

I'm trying to create a simple program which follows a set of commands to automate work that I would otherwise have to type out and click. I would like to know the term for this kind of action on computers.

```
e.g program menu:\ select on parameters > select number 3 > select device > click send
```

I read about the [Rubber Duckey](https://github.com/hak5darren/USB-Rubber-Ducky/wiki/Tutorials) way where guys could [steal facebook passwords from old chrome](https://github.com/hak5darren/USB-Rubber-Ducky/wiki/Payload---Chrome-Password-Stealer) versions by moving around in chrome like:

```
STRING chrome://settings/passwords
ENTER
DELAY 2000
STRING facebook
DELAY 500
TAB
DELAY 500
DOWN
DELAY 500
TAB
....
save to file somewhere
```

I thought it would be cool to make a simple batch or python program to move around in my programs so i dont have to waste so much time clicking on the same things everyday.

I'd be grateful if you could briefly explain this term to me and perhaps send me a few links.

Comment: depends what activities you are trying to automate. Can you be more specific?

Comment: @Takarii I have this video surveillance platform. A lot of the time I have to upgrade Bios and Firmware through FTP and i have to do it for thousands of devices so automatically doing it on the platform would be less painful.

Comment: i'd consider maybe using a console application and the built in scheduler for windows. Will allow you to utilise the .net framework to simplify your workload and make for easy integration into windows